# architecture diagram (current 3.x, 4.x) of joomla architecture

Tags: joomla-3.x, software-architecture, joomla-4

Is there any newer architecture diagram of joomla CMS?

I know the https://docs.joomla.org/Archived%3aCMS_Architecture_in_1.5_and_1.6 but it is from 2011 so pretty outdated.

Also is there one zoom-level in more detail about Joomla CMS architecture?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is nothing like this for Joomla 4 yet. With all the amount of work that's gone into it, there's not a major amount of documentation yet.

You can however use some other resources to help:

- [Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 4](https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_4)
- [Pull Requests for Joomla 4](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+%5B4.0%5D)
- [Joomla 4 Docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Category:Joomla!_4.x)

That said, as far as I'm aware, I don't believe there are major architecture changes that you need to apply when developing an extension.

You may also want to download a copy of Joomla 4 and sift through some of the core extensions to see how they work.

Comment: I see you are a core developer.
Is there no easy way to extract from the source packaging the software architecture of joomla?
(Comming from Java and here I can easily use a UML reverse engineering tool)

Comment: Unfortunately you're asking the wrong person. I was doing UI and Javascript development for Joomla, not the PHP side. Perhaps ask on the [Joomla Forum](https://forum.joomla.org/) or post a new issue on the [Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues)

Comment: This is a pretty old slide, but maybe it helps as well: https://joomla.digital-peak.com/images/blog/JAB17%20Prepare%20you%20extension%20for%20Joomla%204.pdf or this one https://joomla.digital-peak.com/images/blog/JWC17_Prepare_you_extension_for_Joomla_4.pdf